# wordpress - formatting an emailed gift certificate

Tags: php, wordpress, email, html-email

I'm using an [older gift certificate plugin](http://www.suburbanmedia.net/wordpress-plugins/wp-gift-cert) (6 years at least) on my wordpress site and I want to be able to format the way the gift certificate looks. I've emailed the developer with my questions but never received a response so I'm reaching out to anyone that may be able to help me crack this nut.

My questions that I had are:

1. Where and how is the email sent from? Does it originate with my site
   or with Paypal?
2. If it originates from my site, is there a way to format it to make
   it look the way I want it to?

The following link is to the downloaded source files:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0yqpr4p6kePSGtudWJHYWdVQXc&usp=sharing

I've gone through every file trying to track where the email is being sent but I cannot find it.

Comment: It seems the certificate is being constructed in the `wpgft-loader.php` file in the `function send_cert_email($payment_data)` function at line 439

Comment: I was not expecting to hear anything so quickly! I'll start there. Thank you so much. @RST

Comment: @RST I have been searching for so long and I'm not even sure how you found it so quick. You are a lifesaver. Now I can make the gift certificates look decent. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. I am using Sublime Text for coding my own plugins. It easily searches all pages and subfolders in a folder. I searched for "CERT num" as that seemed to appear on the certificate. Good luck.